Placing Right, Left turn arrows on direction path in a turn by turn navigation app in kotlin
I am creating a Turn-by-Turn navigation app the will get its direction data from json file
one of the objects of json file is like this :
    {
        "connector": "",
        "coordinate": {
            "lat": 52.262315,
            "lon": 7.87845
        },
        "distance": 33,
        "orientation": 50,
        "signage": "",
        "streetID": "K 81",
        "streetName": "Industriestraße",
        "symbol": "right",
        "text": "Turn right onto K 81"
    },

when user reaches this lat, lon, he/she should turn and I want to place a turn arrow in that location on path
How they do that in navigations app that the arrow exactly placed in routing path and turns exactly where it should turn.
